# Why not change data in binding XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, xamarin

I create observable collection in class

```
public ObservableCollection<NewsTags> NewsTagsList { get; private set; }

public RelayCommand RefreshNewsTags
{
    get
    {
        return _refreshNewsTagsCommand ?? (
            _refreshNewsTagsCommand = new RelayCommand(
                async () => {
                    var list = await _newsTagsService.GetAllAsync(1, false);
                    foreach (var item in list)
                    {
                        NewsTagsList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
         ));
    }
}
```

And call custom control

```
<tagsListSelector:BoxSelector Items="{Binding NewsTagsList}" />
```

And boxselector.cs

```
public partial class BoxSelector : ContentView
{
    public BoxSelector()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create<BoxSelector, IEnumerable>(
           view => view.ItemsSource,
           null,
           propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {

               ((BoxSelector)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
           }
       );

    private void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindableObject, IEnumerable oldvalue, IEnumerable newvalue)
    {
        boxSelectorGrid.Children.Clear();

        foreach (object obj in newvalue)
        {
            boxSelectorGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text="LOL", TextColor= Color.FromHex("#000")});
        }
    }
```

but no changes.
p.s in newslist.cs NewsTagsList.Count == 10 but in BoxSelector==0

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ItemsSourceChanged method, if the newValue is of type INotifyCollectionChanged you need to wire up the CollectionChanged event, and inside the CollectionChanged code do whatever you want to do when the collection changes. You'll also want to unsubscribe from the event on the oldValue if it is of type INotifyCollectionChanged.

Something like this:

```
        private void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindableObject, IEnumerable oldvalue, IEnumerable newvalue)
    {
        var incc = oldvalue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc != null)
        {
            incc.CollectionChanged -= Incc_CollectionChanged;
        }
        incc = newvalue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc != null)
        {
            incc.CollectionChanged += Incc_CollectionChanged;
        }
        boxSelectorGrid.Children.Clear();

        foreach (object obj in newvalue)
        {
            boxSelectorGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "LOL", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#000") });
        }
    }

    private void Incc_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                // handle Added rows
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                // handle deleting rows
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                // handle moving rows
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                // handle replacing rows
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                // reload everything
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can be an example , please